# iPhone peer 2 peer Connection .. Is there a way to connect to more than 1 devices?

Tags: ios, p2p, gamekit, gksession, gkpeerpickercontroller

I am try to implement peer to peer Connection Application . So i want to Connect  More than 2 devices to each other.How to Create separate session for Each pair of devices 
Is it possible to connect to more than 1 devices using the new GameKit framework?

Comment: I'm not an iPhone dev, but... do you intend to use BlueTooth or wifi as your network system?

Comment: ya this application is based on BlueTooth and wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect multiple devices using [GKSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Take a look at [GKSessionP2P](https://github.com/shrtlist/GKSessionP2P), a demo app that illustrates the ad-hoc networking features of `GKSession`. The app both advertises itself on the local network and automatically connects to available peers, establishing a peer-to-peer network: